# Mode switch (Object/ Edit/ Sculpt) as regular menu, instead of pie menu?

Tags: interface, add-on, edit-mode, object-mode

I am looking for a hotkeyable menu to switch modes with.
There are a couple of addons which do this using a pie menu (Machin3tools is shown below).
[image]

But, I prefer a menu, for changing modes. Like there are menus for Edge commands:
[image]

Is there something like this in Blender or is there any addon that has this?

Comment: You could put all these modes in the Quick Favorites menu (except it will be mixed with other functions if you already use the Quick Favorites)

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/interface/viewport_pies.html

Comment: Specifically look at 'editor switch.'

Comment: That's a pie menu and I am specifically looking for a regular non-pie menu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be fairly easy to modify the pie menu add-ons to create a popup menu.  Rather than do that, I wrote my own add-on.  Save this file with the name "__init__.py" (that's two underbars before and after "init").  Edit your preferences, go to add-ons, and install it.  It's pretty simple and could probably use some additions, most notably it's a pain to change the key it's invoked with.

To use it once it's installed, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>W</kbd> when you have an active object and this menu will popup:

[image: Change mode menu]

The actual modes available will depend on what type of object is active.

You can change the key by editing preferences, going to Keymap and searching for "Change Mode Menu"

UPDATE: I've added a few corrections to the menu draw routine to account for object types I didn't cover in the original.

```py
# Copyright 2022 Martin Fouts
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
# WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTIBILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
# General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program. If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
# 

# Very small add on to start from

bl_info = {
    "name" : "Mode switch menu",
    "description" : "A menu for switching modes in the 3D viewport",
    "author" : "Marty",
    "version" : (0, 0, 1),
    "blender" : (2, 80, 0),
    "location" : "View3D",
    "warning" : "",
    "support" : "COMMUNITY",
    "doc_url" : "",
    "category" : "3D View"
}

import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.types import Menu
from bpy.props import StringProperty

mode_keymap = None

class TLA_OT_changemode(Operator):
    """ Change the mode of an object """
    bl_idname = "tla.changemode"
    bl_label = "Change the 3D viewport mode"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}

    new_mode : StringProperty(name="new mode", description="Mode to change to", default="None")

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return True #context.active_object != None

    def execute(self, context):
        if context.object.mode != self.new_mode:
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = self.new_mode)
        return {'FINISHED'}


class TLA_OT_invokemenu(Operator):
    bl_idname = "tla.invokemenu"
    bl_label = "Change Mode Menu"

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.wm.call_menu(name="TLA_MT_changemode")
        return {'FINISHED'}

class TLA_MT_changemode(Menu):
    """Change Mode menu for View_3d"""
    bl_label = "MODE"
    bl_idname = "TLA_MT_changemode"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "TLA"

    def draw(self, context):
        object = context.active_object
        if not object:
            return
        self.layout.operator("tla.changemode", text="Object").new_mode='OBJECT'
        if object.type == 'ARMATURE':
            self.layout.operator("tla.changemode", text="Edit").new_mode='EDIT'
            self.layout.operator("tla.changemode", text="Pose").new_mode='POSE'
        elif object.type == 'MESH':
            self.layout.operator("tla.changemode", text="Edit").new_mode='EDIT'
            self.layout.operator("tla.changemode", text="Sculpt").new_mode='SCULPT'
            self.layout.operator("tla.changemode", text="Vertex Paint").new_mode='VERTEX_PAINT'
            self.layout.operator("tla.changemode", text="Weight Paint").new_mode='WEIGHT_PAINT'
            self.layout.operator("tla.changemode", text="Texture Paint").new_mode='TEXTURE_PAINT'
        elif object.type in {'CURVE', 'SURFACE', 'META', 'FONT'}:
            self.layout.operator("tla.changemode", text="Edit").new_mode='EDIT'
        elif object.type == 'GPENCIL':
            self.layout.operator("tla.changemode", text="Edit").new_mode='EDIT_GPENCIL'
            self.layout.operator("tla.changemode", text="Sculpt").new_mode='SCULPT_GPENCIL'
            self.layout.operator("tla.changemode", text="Paint").new_mode='PAINT_GPENCIL'
            self.layout.operator("tla.changemode", text="Weight Paint").new_mode='WEIGHT_GPENCIL'
            self.layout.operator("tla.changemode", text="Vertex Paint").new_mode='VERTEX_GPENCIL'
        elif object.type == 'LATTICE':
            self.layout.operator("tla.changemode", text="Edit").new_mode='EDIT'
            self.layout.operator("tla.changemode", text="Weight Paint").new_mode='WEIGHT_PAINT'
 
classes = [
    TLA_OT_changemode,
    TLA_OT_invokemenu,
    TLA_MT_changemode,
]

def register():
    key_config = bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs.addon
    if key_config:
        key_map = key_config.keymaps.new(name='3D View', space_type='VIEW_3D')
        key_entry = key_map.keymap_items.new("tla.invokemenu",
                                            type='W',
                                            value='PRESS',
                                            ctrl=True,
    )
    mode_keymap = (key_map, key_entry)
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(c)


def unregister():
    if mode_keymap:
        key_map, key_entry = mode_keymap
        key_map.keymap_items.remove(key_entry)
        bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.remove(key_map)
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(c)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

I've made the add-on available on [github](https://github.com/martyfouts/change-mode-menu). If you're reading this in the future, please check there for the latest version.

Comment: .don't think you could ask for a better answer than that! :D

Comment: @RobinBetts Thank you for that very high praise.

Comment: thanks, nice alternative to the pie menu

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for!
@MartyFouts: Is it possible to rename  "__ init __.py" to something like "ModesMenu.py"? Then I can distinguish the addon in the list of all other addons ;)

Comment: @Hologram I think that will work but I haven't tried it.  Alternately you can now download the zip file from [github](https://github.com/martyfouts/change-mode-menu) by going to the "Code" button and selecting "download zip".  If you install the zip file it will give you the name "change mode menu".

Comment: @moonboots you're welcome.  I'm not sure I've gotten all of the available options right so do let me know if I need to change anything.

Comment: @Marty Fouts I've tried to assign it the Ctrl Tab shortcut but for some reason it didn't work, not sure why...

Comment: @moonboots di you remove the "Object Mode Menu" entry for ctrl-tab first?  I know ctrl-tab gets used in about a dozen different places so I decided not to try to override it in the add-on.

Comment: Ok thanks it fixes it  ;)

Comment: I personally moved the addon over to the "Window" section of the keymap editor, this is where the original was located. Make sure to search for Ctrl Tab in the keymap editor and disable all other asignments @moonboots

Comment: This certainly works nice, thanks a lot @MartyFouts. I'll be sure to let you know over on Github if I notice anything. I like that you don't need to do an explicit selection, deselecting the object in the viewport, but having it active in the outliner works just fine too!

Comment: @Hologram when you say "moved to Window" do you mean you set `bl_region_type` to `'WINDOW'` instead of `'UI'`?  If so, I can make that change in the github version.

Comment: @MartyFouts I mean changing the context from, if I recall correctly, 3D view to Window. I'll let you know on Github as I can't post an image here.